# How do I add a fixed row to bottom of a Google visualization table

Tags: php, javascript, google-visualization

I currently am creating a table with Google visualization that has a bunch of data with a totals row along the bottom. I am getting an array of data using ajax from a PHP file which looks something like this,

```
myarray = array(
    0 => array(
        'cols' => array(0 => array('v' => 'data', 'p' => 'data')),
        'rows' => array(0 => array('v' => 'data', 'p' => 'data'))
    )
);
```

When the header columns are clicked on the data sorts which is cool, but the totals row is also sorting which is not cool. I have looked all over the web trying to find the best solution to this but I have not yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no direct way to do this provided by the api. In the past I've gotten around this by just generating a second 'summary' table, (gviz, or maybe something else if you'd like it to stand out a bit) which holds relevant totals, and never changes.

Alternatively, you code presort the table by the most relevant column, then disallow sorting on the table in the UI.